# what will i do if i want to enter a char to the value of a,b,c then it will say "error"?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a,b,c,d,X,Y;
    float x1,x2;
    char ans,i;

    do
    {
         cout << "Welcome!" <<endl
              << "To my Simple Machine" <<endl
              <<endl
              << "Enter the value of a:" <<endl;
         cin >>a;
         cout << "Enter the value of b:" <<endl;
         cin >>b;
         cout << "Enter the value of c:" <<endl;
         cin >>c;

         d=b*b-4*a*c;
         x1=(-1*b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
         x2=(-1*b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
         X=-b/2*a;
```

if the user will enter a char on a,b,c i want to display error

```
         if(a==0)
         {
                 cout << "You are now solvin a Linear Eq'n" <<endl;
                 Y=-c/b;
                 cout << "The value of Y is:" <<Y<<endl
                      <<endl
                      << "Do you want to repeat?" <<endl
                      << "Loading...." <<endl;
         }
         else if(d==0)
         {
              cout << "You are now solving a Quadratic Eq'n" <<endl
                   << "The value of d is:" <<d<<endl
                   << "x1 is:" <<x1<<endl
                   << "x2 is:" <<x2<<endl
                   <<endl
                   << "Do you want to repeat?" <<endl
                   << "Loading...." <<endl;
         }
         else if(d>0)
         {
              cout << "You are now solving a Quadratic Eq'n" <<endl
                   << "The value of d is:" <<d<<endl
                   << "x1 is:" <<x1<<endl
                   << "x2 is:" <<x2<<endl
                   <<endl
                   << "Do you want to repeat?" <<endl
                   << "Loading...." <<endl;
         }
         else if(d<0)
         {
              cout << "You are now solving a Quadratic Eq'n" <<endl
                   << "The value of d is:" <<d<<endl
                   << "x1 is:" <<X<<"+"<<sqrt(-d)/2*a<<'i'<<endl
                   << "x2 is:" <<X<<"-"<<sqrt(-d)/2*a<<'i'<<endl
                   <<endl
                   << "Do you want to repeat?" <<endl
                   << "Loading...." <<endl;
         }
         cout.setf(ios::fixed);
         cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
         cout.precision(2);
    }while(ans=='y' ||ans=='Y');
         cout << "End of Program..." <<endl
                         << "Thank You!" <<endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

I can't compile it 'cause it says g++.exe was not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the **exact** error you're getting.

Comment: "I can't compile it 'cause it says g++.exe was not working"  -  Maybe your g++ is corrupt?

Comment: If your desktop compiler isnt working. Try with an online one for the time being. http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I read you right, you want to display a message if the user enters anything other than a floating point value? Then you can do it by remembering that a stream can be used as a [boolean value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) and also remember that e.g. the input operator returns the stream. So you can do e.g.

```
if (!(cin >> a))
{
    std::cout << "Error: Illegal input\n";
}
```

To clear the error bits which gets set by the illegal input, you use [`std::basic_ios::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Answer (score 0):

You should store it in a `char` variable, check if it is a numeric entry then assign it to `double`.

```
double b;char tmpChar;
cout << "Enter the value of b:" <<endl;
cin >>tmpChar;
if ((tmpChar >= 'a' && tmpChar <= 'z') || (tmpChar >='A' && tmpChar <='Z'))
   error();
```